# Google+ Sign-in: how to check Sign-in status on app start (AngularJS)?

Tags: angularjs, google-api

I implemented Google+'s Sign-in in my AngularJS application.

However when, on app start, I check if the user already signed-in, checkSessionState returns **false** every time.

```
        gapi.auth.checkSessionState({
            client_id: $scope.Oauth2Parameters.clientId
        },$scope.loginWithExistingTokenPlus);


    $scope.loginWithExistingTokenPlus = function(session_state){
        var auth_token = gapi.auth.getToken();
        if (session_state){
            console.log(auth_token.access_token);
        } else { // this branch is triggered every time
            console.log("[DEBUG] Google Signin not done yet");
        }

    }
```

I'm sure the Signin works because in gapi.auth.authorize's callback I have

```
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) { // this branch is triggered correctly
            $scope.signInActions();
            $scope.checkSignInStatus();
        } else {
            $scope.signOutActions();
            // signInButton.onclick = $scope.handleAuthClick;
        }
```

**EDIT**:

following **user1405141**'s advice I tried with:

```
    $scope.checkSignInStatus = function(){
        gapi.auth.checkSessionState({
            session_state: null
        },$scope.loginWithExistingTokenPlus);
    }
```

and with

```
    $scope.checkSignInStatus = function(){
        gapi.auth.checkSessionState({
            session_state: null,
            client_id: $scope.Oauth2Parameters.clientId
        },$scope.loginWithExistingTokenPlus);
    }
```

as well. But the result didn't change.

Answer (score 1):

gapi.auth.checkSessionState() requires that session_state be set to null in order to actually check:

```
gapi.auth.checkSessionState({session_state: null}, function(isUserNotLoggedIn){}
```

https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript

Comment: thank you for your asnwer.
however I just tried and I get the exact same result.
any clue? (please see my updated question)

Comment: your second version looks ok. Did you try to hardcode the client_id value?

Comment: by the way, consider carefully the intention of checkSessionState() with sessionParams.session_state = null ; it is intended to "check if the user is signed in to Google, whether or not they have previously authorized your app."

Comment: regarding your second comment : how do I verify if the user is logged in Google and HAS authorized my app?

Comment: I tried to harcore it. no way.
It seems ignoring my request